# htaccess and codeigniter wrong redirection weird question mark in URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

When I write manually in the browser "example.com/page" the browser redirects to "example.com/?page/"
This, of course, opens my homepage and not the required "/page/"

I have intentionally added a few redirects in my htaccess file because I need these 3 features:

- www to non-www
- http to https
- forcing trailing slash at the end of the URLs

I also use Codeigniter 3 as a PHP framework for my website.

I tried many examples and read a lot of similar questions for the last few weeks. No success.

Here is my full htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


# Redirects www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


# Force ending url traling slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]



# Prevent CI index.php

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$0 [L]

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Redirects http to https protocol
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


# Redirect index.php to the root /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# One month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>

RedirectPermanent /free-project-management-certification/ https://bvop.org/projectmanagement/
RedirectPermanent /free-scrum-master-certification/ https://bvop.org/scrummaster/
RedirectPermanent /product-owner-certification/ https://bvop.org/productowner/
RedirectPermanent /human-resources-management-certification/ https://bvop.org/humanresources/
RedirectPermanent /product-management-certification/ https://bvop.org/productmanagement/
RedirectPermanent /project-management-certification/ https://bvop.org/projectmanagement/

RedirectPermanent /index.php/ https://bvop.org/


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

I changed positions of all redirects, tried different combinations, changed characters, a lot of things.
I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You are not redirecting [http non www] to [https non www] you should add
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I have checked your .htaccess on [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it is working fine, so there might be some conflicts with other rules that are not in your .htacess

Comment: @AhmedSheashaa The directive is already there to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (non-www), but it's in the wrong place - which is the problem. (However, there are other potential issues with mixing mod_alias and mod_rewrite redirects.) Unfortunately, the _MWL tester tool_ you linked to doesn't support the necessary syntax (it also doesn't handle the L flag properly or follow redirects). There are actually 3 external redirects plus an internal rewrite (in the middle) that results in the malformed redirect as stated above.

Comment: Cross-site post on the [Webmasters stack](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) which has an accepted answer: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130251/apache-rewrite-rule-www-to-non-www-http-to-https-add-trailing-slash